# App terminated and SharedPreferences Deleted first time it's launched

Tags: android

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution for this really strange problem :

When the app is launched for the first time after installation. it's stays up working perfectly for a minute and then it closes.
right after When I launch it again I find that all the data that was previously created during that one minute is wiped (SharedPreferences + Sqlite Data) but the app doesn't close again and it works normally (Issue happens only when the app is launched for the very first time after installation)

I couldn't figure out the cause of the problem since no Error is showing on the device neither on Android Studio (All it shows on the Run Section is "Application terminated").

- I don't think it have anything to do with the code in the activities (It doesn't matter what activity Is first launched the app always closes)

THIS IS THE LOGCAT

```
02-16 16:03:56.965 987-1456/? I/AudioService: getStreamVolume 3 index 0
02-16 16:03:56.975 28996-3478/? W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.923ms
02-16 16:03:57.055 987-1108/? E/BackupManagerService: Timeout restoring application com.myapp.xxxx
02-16 16:03:57.055 987-1108/? V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.myapp.xxxx
02-16 16:03:57.065 987-1108/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.myapp.xxxx appid=10796 user=0: clear data
02-16 16:03:57.065 987-1108/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 3100:com.myapp.xxxx /u0a796 (adj 0): stop com.myapp.xxxx cause clear data
02-16 16:03:57.065 987-1108/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3100
02-16 16:03:57.065 987-1108/? W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{d2836da u0 com.myapp.xxxx/.WelcomeActivity t1689}: app died, no saved state
02-16 16:03:57.075 987-1108/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
02-16 16:03:57.095 18814-18828/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 83287(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 92(4MB) LOS objects, 23% free, 25MB/33MB, paused 2.146ms total 343.743ms
02-16 16:03:57.105 987-1108/? D/InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 3100
02-16 16:03:57.125 255-742/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3653 Removed XelcomeActi (4/7)
02-16 16:03:57.125 255-6235/? I/SurfaceFlinger: id=3653 Removed XelcomeActi (-2/7)
02-16 16:03:57.135 987-1108/? D/InputDispatcher: Focused application released
02-16 16:03:57.135 987-1018/? E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Comment: Then, where is your code and logcat?

Comment: Thanks! @GenoChen I added Logcat to the post what other code should I add ?

Comment: Prepare the logcat capturing environment (for example, set filter to "current application" and select the right application), produce the crash, copy the error produced at the time of crash, paste them to this question.

Comment: @GenoChen I edited the logcat can you please have a look at it again ?

Comment: No, this is still not the scene of crash, but the scene of all unrelated application running.

Comment: Many of the crash scene is like a Java stacktrace, for example "java.lang.XxxException: A detailed reason" with a list of "package.Class(file:lineno)".

Comment: I know what you mean but The problem is that when the app get terminated like  there is no errors like what you mentioned.

Comment: Then you can fire another question on StackOverflow, with the unknown reason about no error in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may get the same problem:
the reason the app stops is the backupmanagerservice like the logcat shows :

```
E/BackupManagerService: Timeout restoring application com.myapp.xxxx
V/ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationStateBlocked userId 0 pkgname com.myapp.xxxx
I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.myapp.xxxx appid=10796 user=0: clear data
I/ActivityManager: Killing 3100:com.myapp.xxxx /u0a796 (adj 0): stop com.myapp.xxxx cause clear data
D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 3100
W/ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{d2836da u0 com.myapp.xxxx/.WelcomeActivity t1689}: app died, no saved state
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

I fixed it by adding this line in AndroidManifest file:

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```